# implementation of DFT in C++

Tags: c++, cimg, dft

I want to implement the **DFT** (Discrete Fourier Transform) in **C++** language to process **images**.

[image: formula for 1D DFT]

As I was studying the theory, I got to know, that I can divide the 2D DFT into **two 1D DFT** parts. Firstly, for each row I perform 1D DFT then I do it for each column. Of course, I should make operations on **complex numbers**.

Here occur some problems, because I am not sure where to use real, and where imaginary part of the complex number. I found somewhere, that the values of the input image pixels I should treat as a real part with the imaginary part set as 0.

I made an implementation of that, but I suppose that the result image is incorrect.

[image: lenac][image: lenac_dft]

I would be grateful if someone could help me with that one.

For reading and saving images I use [CImg library](http://www.cimg.eu/).

```
void DFT (CImg<unsigned char> image)
{
    int w=512;
    int h=512;
    int rgb=3;
    complex <double> ***obrazek=new complex <double>**[w];
    for (int b=0;b<w;b++) //making 3-dimensional table to store DFT values
    {
        obrazek[b]=new complex <double>*[h];
        for (int a=0;a<h;a++)
        {
            obrazek[b][a]=new complex <double>[rgb];
        }
    }

    CImg<unsigned char> kopia(image.width(),image.height(),1,3,0);

    complex<double> sum=0;
    complex<double> sum2=0;
    double pi = 3.14;

    for (int i=0; i<512; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<512; j++){
    for (int c=0; c<3; c++){
        complex<double> cplx(image(i,j,c), 0);
        obrazek[i][j][c]=cplx;
    }}}

    for (int c=0; c<3; c++) //for rows
    {
            for (int y=0; y<512; y++)
            {
                sum=0;
                for (int x=0; x<512; x++)
                {
                    sum+=(obrazek[x][y][c].real())*cos((2*pi*x*y)/512)-(obrazek[x][y][c].imag())*sin((2*pi*x*y)/512);
                    obrazek[x][y][c]=sum;
                }
            }
    }

    for (int c=0; c<3; c++) //for columns
    {
            for (int y=0; y<512; y++)//r
            {
                sum2=0;
                for (int x=0; x<512; x++)
                {
                    sum2+=(obrazek[y][x][c].real())*cos((2*pi*x*y)/512)-(obrazek[y][x][c].imag())*sin((2*pi*x*y)/512);
                    obrazek[y][x][c]=sum2;
                }
            }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<512; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<512; j++){
    for (int c=0; c<3; c++){
        kopia(i,j,c)=obrazek[i][j][c].real();
    }}}

    CImgDisplay image_disp(kopia,"dft");

    while (!image_disp.is_closed() )
    {

        image_disp.wait();

    }
    saving(kopia);
}
```

Comment: How have you tried to debug this?  For example, have you tried computing the DFT of a very simple input data-set (e.g. the identity matrix or an all-ones matrix), or at least simplifying your code to only work with grayscale images (as opposed to RGB)?

Comment: I will make one observation, though: Your value of `pi` is woefully inaccurate.  You should use 3.141592653589793.

Comment: I will make some other observations: Your complex multiplication is wrong.  And your 1D DFTs are fundamentally wrong (there should be a 4D loop, not a 3D loop).  I suggest you start from scratch; first write a function that correctly multiplies complex numbers, then a routine that generates the complex exponential terms, then a function that combines these to perform a 1D DFT.  You can then wrap this in a function that performs 2D DFTs, and then finally another wrapper function that calculates the DFT for each colour-plane.